# Is it possible to transfer provider from one SIM card to another?

Tags: cellphone, mobile, sim, smartphones, mobile-phones

Is it possible to overwrite (migrate) provider info and details from one SIM card into another SIM card (not blank, but another working SIM card), so, when I insert that new card, the phone could continue receiving calls/internet like it did with old card?

How can it be done and what tools could be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that "another" SIM card is not a blank one then most likely no, you can't.

Even if you can, the new SIM will likely fail on network authentication due to the unknown or mismatched authentication keys. The section that stores authentication keys are write-protected so once this section is written you can't overwrite any info.

If you use a blank SIM then you can clone the existing one. There are commercial tools for cloning purposes but I'm not going to give any specific product name as it's off-topic (shopping-related).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Cloning a SIM by end-users rather than authorised services might be ILLEGAL.

Answer (score 2):

The subscriber identity module includes secrets known only to the provider, the only way is to get a replacement SIM from the cellular service provider and then have them change the account to use the new SIM.